# How to extract the ridgelines of a DEM using Python?

Tags: gis, raster, gdal, rasterio

If I want to extract ridgelines from a TIFF-format DEM using Python, what should I do?

I would like someone to provide Python 3 code for extracting ridgelines from a DEM, rather than using arcpy.I really don't know how to solve it